# Excel formula need assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to know the formula for the below

if 40% of A1 is less than 15000 then A2 =15000 else A2 should be equal to 40% of A1.

What i want is A2 should not be less than 15000.

Thanks much in advance!!

Comment: =IF((a1*.4)<15000,15000,a1*.4)

Answer (score 3):

```
=IF((A1*0.4)<15000,15000,A1*0.4)
```

`IF` is explained [over here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php).

Alternatively, you can use:

```
=MAX(15000,A1*0.4)
```

`MAX` is explained [over here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/max.php).

Comment: @RajiRaj If you find this answer acceptable, feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.